# How to create new date field using CASE in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I'm creating a dashboard of marketing leads from a Data Source that has two columns of dates in it. One of the columns is historic dates that were imported. One of the columns is all new leads, with accurate dates.

I'm trying to create a new field in Data Studio for use as the Date Range Dimensions. Essentially, if historic date is null, then use new date. If it isn't null, use the historic date.

This is my current code:

```
CASE
  WHEN Historic Date IS NULL THEN Created Date
  ELSE Created Date
END
```

There are no errors thrown when creating the field, but when I set it as the Date Range Dimension, I get this error:

> This data source was improperly configured.
>
> Invalid argument type.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Case function has as output a string which cannot be recognized or configured as a date in google Studio. It can be a bug from Data Studio, but the fact is that I have the same problem and I solve it converting the output of case into a date format.

I have no much time to explain/expose it better, therefore I will put the function that worked for me:

```
todate(CASE 
    WHEN Status IN ("X","NMX","MX") THEN Cancel Dt cf
    ELSE Confirm Dt cf
END
,'%Y%m%d','%Y%m%d')
```

Hope it fixes you well you or at least gives you some light/direction on how to solve it.